# How to send and receive image through using ServerSocket Service?

Tags: android, service, serversocket

I am trying to sending and receiving image to display in `ImageView` using Server-socket, I want to decrypt image using server-socket but its not working.

Image url like this :

```
http://localhost:4545/sdcard0/emulated/test.img;
```

Service :

```
public class ImageDecrptService extends Service {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket socket;

    void acceptRequestNDecryptFile() {
        try {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4545);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            while (true) {
                Log.e("", "thread called true");
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                //some thing code
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                acceptRequestNDecryptFile();
                Log.e("", "thread called ");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        try {
            thread.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

How can pass image url to server socket?

Note : I do not want use Bitmap to display image.

Comment: Please explain your setup better. Who tries to download the image? And who is serving it?

Comment: @greenapps..Its not downloading image, It is exist in local storage(Directory),Its displaying from local service to decrypt image and display to ImageView

Comment: ???? You told not enough. Decrypt? Service? Only to display a local image? Whats going on? You should start with much better telling your setup. We have to guess now. And if you have a server than tell also something of your client.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a http url of an image on a webserver then you would need a client to grab the image.

So your ServerSocket is of no use.

Also a client-Socket would not be the right way to go.

You need to use a http component or library to download the image.

Or invoke the DownloadManager.